Sync Gradle Failed
i have some problem in build gradle in the android ide app
my app varsion is 2.5.0 and i download it from gethub
my ram is 4
and i have storage
i try to sync project and i get some error i also download every think like
android sdk
android jdk
thats my error`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/CpEditor/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 4m 5s
VCS Checkout Cache (/storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/CpEditor/.gradle/vcs-1) removing files not accessed on or after Thu Jul 04 20:01:54 GMT 2024.
VCS Checkout Cache (/storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/CpEditor/.gradle/vcs-1) cleanup deleted 0 files/directories.
VCS Checkout Cache (/storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/CpEditor/.gradle/vcs-1) cleaned up in 0.025 secs.


If it s a public GitHub repo you are trying to build please include the link in your question. Or include the relevant part of the Gradle config in your question.
